# The code doesnt return anything past the questions for the integers

Tags: c, codeblocks

i'm doing an assignment but i cant figure out how to make the code run to the number 2147483647 and then for it to stop and turn back a message like "invalid" etc? also it keeps returning the line with if else saying there needs to be a parentheses before the else?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int result;
    int a, x, n;
    printf("Enter values of a: ");
    scanf("%d ", &a);
    printf("and x: ");
    scanf("%d ", &x);
    printf("Enter the exponent value: ");
    scanf("%d ", &n);
    if (result < 2147483647)
    {
        result = a + pow(x,n);
    }
    printf("\n%d", result);
    if else {
        printf("Invalid");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i tried fixing it a couple times but im only a first year in c so i dont rlly get it tbh :/

Comment: You seem to have skipped some parts in your text-books, tutorials or classes. Like what is the default values for uninitialized local variables, and how `if` and `else` works.

Comment: What value do you expect `result` to have at the line `if (result < 2147483647)`?

Comment: I would judge that your code is running completely from start through to the end and it is giving you the correct outputs for how it is coded, just not how you intended. Consider coding rule #1 - variable/parameter initialisation; then as stated, reread description of `if ... else...`

Comment: @ChrisBD Considering that the shown code won't even build, there won't be any output to consider.

Comment: Checking for overflow is hard.  Yes, on a 32-bit machine, a signed `int` can't represent integers greater than 2147483647.  But if you've computed a result in an `int` variable `result`, and you're wondering whether it overflowed, you can *not* simply write something like `if(result < 2147483647)`!  Since `result` can *not* hold a number greater than 2147483647, it can not hold whatever too-big value you tried to compute, so even if you fix the control-flow issues, you're never going to hit your `printf("Invalid")` case this way.

Answer (score 0):

Code review:

1. Initialisation required.

   ```
    int result;
   ```
2. Initialisation not required (with current code structure) but recommended good practice.

   ```
    int a, x, n;
   ```
3. Where does `result` value come from?
4. What value do you expect `result` to have here? Is there missing code prior to this line?

   ```
    if (result < 2147483647)
   ```
5. In

   ```
    if (result < 2147483647)
    {
        result = a + pow(x,n);
    }
    printf("\n%d", result);
    if else {
        printf("Invalid");
    }
   ```

Is `printf("\n%d", result);` expected to run only when `if (result < 2147483647)` because it will currently always be run?

6. This is incorrect - recheck your understanding of `if ... else...` syntax.

   ```
    if else {
        printf("Invalid");
    }
   ```
7. Remember `{` and `}` are to show the start and end of a block of code. If the line preceding `{` is a logical check without `;` line terminator, then the block will be run if the logical check passes.

I suspect that your `result` value is only meant to be calculated and set by `result = a + pow(x,n);`
and that you wish to check the result of that calculation and then print either the value or "Invalid".

If this is the case, then remember that code is run in sequence from top to bottom, even if an instruction sends you back to rerun some code again. Thus, you should set the value of `result` before you check its value.